# Is it possible to send a virtual desktop to another monitor on another computer over the network?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, external-display

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid on an Alienware m15x laptop with the proprietary nVidia drivers. GNOME, Compiz, etc.

First, I have two computers, an Alienware m15x laptop (which is my primary computer) and an old desktop computer.

Here's the situation. My Alienware m15x only has 1 display port. I'm using that to connect to an external HD monitor. I would like to use yet another external monitor.

My desktop computer has 2 display ports, 1 for VGA and 1 for DVI. It is currently also connected to my external HD monitor with a VGA cable.

I was wondering if I could use another monitor, plug that into my desktop, and then make it emulate another desktop for my laptop over my local network.

Is this possible? I don't mind doing some dirty X11 hack to get it to work if anything like it is. I also thought about the possibility of sending a Compiz virtual workspace to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a blog entry describing a Xdmx setup:
http://blogs.unbolt.net/index.php/brinley/2007/09/17/simple_xdmx_setup_with_gdm. Xdmx is included in ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

A friend in IRC linked me to a video that shows how to use a program called `Xdmx` to do basically just what I want. The video can be found here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOzRCBGDVaE