# How to use a networked Android TV as second monitor

Tags: linux, networking, multiple-monitors, android

I have an old Sony "Google TV" connected to my local network. What's the easiest way to use it as a second monitor on Linux (Ubuntu) without using a direct video cable (i.e. only over the network)?

It runs Android, but it's an old version and even then the platform is not a standard environment, so a lot of apps won't work with it even if they support its version of Android.

I've heard of some "[extreme multihead](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extreme_Multihead)" tools that form a common desktop from monitors on separate machines, but I haven't seen any that work with Linux+Android. e.g. What I'm asking is similar to [these](https://superuser.com/questions/342292/is-it-possible-to-send-a-virtual-desktop-to-another-monitor-on-another-computer) [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/353563/extend-own-desktop-with-another-one-over-the-network-in-linux), but those only explain how to accomplish this amount Linux and Windows machines.